# How do I properly send parameters and headers for swagger client get?

Tags: node.js, swagger

Currently checking out https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-client. The docs are a bit confusing to me.

I intend to hit a URL like `www.mysite.com/topic/:topicName`

I tried a few things like this:

```
  const authHeaders = {
    'X-Api-Key': 'mykey',
    Authorization: `Bearer mytoken`,
  };
  const topic = await client.apis.Topic.getTopic({
    headers: authHeaders,
    parameters: {
      topicName: 'myName'
    }
  });
```

I can't seem to figure the right way to send headers and fill in the variable from the swagger docs to form the URL. I'd seen examples where the headers are the first argument so I also had tried

```
  const topic = await client.apis.Topic.getTopic(authHeaders, {
    parameters: {
      topicName: 'myName'
    }
  });
```

When I look at the docs for the word headers, they just talk about setting up the initial client. I figure making it send the auth headers every time is another good solution so I'm kind of looking for both ways (since either can make sense depending on the header).

Answer (score 0):

Using the swagger-client is a little different that a regular http client because it follow exactly your swagger file, you will have to provide the parameters that your swagger spec describes.
for swagger client v3, this format works for me:

```
Swagger({ 
  url: "www.example.org/swagger.json",
  authorization: {
    // This must be described in your swagger file, if not, will be ignored.
    // See https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/bearer-authentication/
    bearerAuth: {type: 'apiKey', 'in': 'header', name: 'Authorization'}
  }
}).then(client => {
  client.apis.Topic.getTopic({
    // The parameters need to be described in the swagger file, or will be ignored.
    // Also make sure that the getTopic operation describes that uses the bearerAuth
    // Or swagger-client will not send the Auth credentials.
    topicName: "myName"
  }).then(response => {
    // Do magic.
  })
});
```

The swagger portion for your getTopic operation should be similar to this:

```
{
  "/rest/3/topic/{topicName}": {
    "tags": ["topic"]
    "operationId": "getTopic"
    "get": {
      "parameters": [
        {
          "name": "topicName", "in": "path", "required": true, "type": "string"
        } 
      ],
      "security": { "basicAuth": "global" }
    }
  }
}
```